# My C# code using System.IO.StreamWriter outputs random chinese/unicode characters at a certain length

Tags: c#, math, primes, streamwriter

I have been attempting to write code to output all primes from 3 to `int limit` in a document (using System.IO.StreamWriter), as well as to a console. This is the code I wrote:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace primes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string output = "";
            a:
            Console.Write("Numbers to test >> ");
            string limitStr = Console.ReadLine();
            int limit = Convert.ToInt32(limitStr);
            if (limit < 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Write an integer above 2.\n");
                goto a;
            }
            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
            for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 2; j < i; j++)
                {
                    if (j == Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(i / 2)) + 1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(i + " is prime.");
                        output += Convert.ToString(Convert.ToString(i) + "\n");
                    }
                    else if (i % j == 0)
                    {
                        goto b;
                    }
                }
                b:;
            }
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("primes.txt")) 
            {
                sw.Write(output);
            }
            string timeElapsed = Convert.ToString((DateTime.Now - start).TotalSeconds);
            Console.Write("\nTook " + timeElapsed + " seconds to run.");

            ConsoleKeyInfo k;

            Console.WriteLine("\nPress ESC to exit...");
            while (true)
            {
                k = Console.ReadKey(true);
                if (k.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

When using `int limit = 50` I get this output in the text document:

```
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
31
37
41
43
47
```

But when `int limit = 1260`, it outputs this:

```
ਲ਼ਵ਷ㄱㄊਲ਼㜱ㄊਹ㌲㈊ਹㄳ㌊਷ㄴ㐊ਲ਼㜴㔊ਲ਼㤵㘊਱㜶㜊਱㌷㜊ਹ㌸㠊ਹ㜹ㄊ㄰ㄊ㌰ㄊ㜰ㄊ㤰ㄊ㌱ㄊ㜲ㄊㄳㄊ㜳ㄊ㤳ㄊ㤴ㄊㄵㄊ㜵ㄊ㌶ㄊ㜶ㄊ㌷ㄊ㤷ㄊㄸㄊㄹㄊ㌹ㄊ㜹ㄊ㤹㈊ㄱ㈊㌲㈊㜲㈊㤲㈊㌳㈊㤳㈊ㄴ㈊ㄵ㈊㜵㈊㌶㈊㤶㈊ㄷ㈊㜷㈊ㄸ㈊㌸㈊㌹㌊㜰㌊ㄱ㌊㌱㌊㜱㌊ㄳ㌊㜳㌊㜴㌊㤴㌊㌵㌊㤵㌊㜶㌊㌷㌊㤷㌊㌸㌊㤸㌊㜹㐊㄰㐊㤰㐊㤱㐊ㄲ㐊ㄳ㐊㌳㐊㤳㐊㌴㐊㤴㐊㜵㐊ㄶ㐊㌶㐊㜶㐊㤷㐊㜸㐊ㄹ㐊㤹㔊㌰㔊㤰㔊ㄲ㔊㌲㔊ㄴ㔊㜴㔊㜵㔊㌶㔊㤶㔊ㄷ㔊㜷㔊㜸㔊㌹㔊㤹㘊㄰㘊㜰㘊㌱㘊㜱㘊㤱㘊ㄳ㘊ㄴ㘊㌴㘊㜴㘊㌵㘊㤵㘊ㄶ㘊㌷㘊㜷㘊㌸㘊ㄹ㜊㄰㜊㤰㜊㤱㜊㜲㜊㌳㜊㤳㜊㌴㜊ㄵ㜊㜵㜊ㄶ㜊㤶㜊㌷㜊㜸㜊㜹㠊㤰㠊ㄱ㠊ㄲ㠊㌲㠊㜲㠊㤲㠊㤳㠊㌵㠊㜵㠊㤵㠊㌶㠊㜷㠊ㄸ㠊㌸㠊㜸㤊㜰㤊ㄱ㤊㤱㤊㤲㤊㜳㤊ㄴ㤊㜴㤊㌵㤊㜶㤊ㄷ㤊㜷㤊㌸㤊ㄹ㤊㜹ㄊ〰ਹ〱㌱ㄊ㄰ਹ〱ㄲㄊ㌰਱〱㌳ㄊ㌰ਹ〱㤴ㄊ㔰਱〱ㄶㄊ㘰ਲ਼〱㤶ㄊ㠰਷〱ㄹㄊ㤰ਲ਼〱㜹ㄊ〱ਲ਼ㄱ㤰ㄊㄱ਷ㄱ㌲ㄊ㈱ਹㄱㄵㄊ㔱ਲ਼ㄱ㌶ㄊ㜱਱ㄱㄸㄊ㠱਷ㄱ㌹ㄊ〲਱㈱㌱ㄊㄲ਷㈱㌲ㄊ㈲ਹ㈱ㄳㄊ㌲਷㈱㤴ㄊ㔲ਹ
```

This jargon continues with larger and larger numbers, with more characters, sometimes with some pattern for a little while in the text. What am I doing wrong? It appears just fine in the console.

Information: Using Visual Studio Community 2019 to edit

Using Windows 10 Home Notepad.exe to access `primes.txt`

Comment: Please don't use goto's. #spaghetticode

The "goto a" can be replaced with a while loop.
The "goto b" can replaced with a simple "break".

Comment: @BryanWilliams That's what code to use! I just kind-of threw it together as a test because I forgot the formatting.

Comment: That is "3\n5\n7\n...", encoded as utf16.  Whatever text viewer you use doesn't know it is utf8 text.  Notepad tries to auto-detect if the file is missing a BOM, sometimes it guesses wrong.  Not unlikely to happen when the end-of-line is \n instead of \r\n.  How *that* happened is hard to guess, you'd have to run the code on a *nix machine to get that wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify text encoding type on your StreamWriter output to your text file.

Replace:

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("primes.txt"))
```

with

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("primes.txt", false, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
```